# How to throw SystemException in java?

Tags: exception, try-catch, java-7, throw

I saw many people wrote like:

```
try {
       //something
}
catch (IOException e){
    throw new SystemException("IO Error", e);
}
```

I got `"Cannot instantiate the type SystemException"` error and it seems SystemException is a abstract class, how can I able to throw it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is an abstract class and that means that it does not make sense to construct an object of type `SystemException`. It is recommended to use more meaningful exceptions types.

You have mentioned `IOException` in your code. This means an exception related to an I/O operation and the catcher can act accordingly (maybe a special log level, some I/O cleanup etc.).

In your particular case, I think you should change it to:

```
try {
    //something
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // log exception info and other context information here
    // e.g. e.printStackTrace(); 

    // just rethrowing the exception (call stack is still there)
    throw e;
}
```

P.S. Quite offtopic, but coming from .NET world I have found about the [subtle difference](http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000352.html) between `throw ex;` in `C#` vs. `Java`.

Comment: so what I possibly should write in catch is something like below? Thanks
e.printStackTrace();
throw e;

Comment: @Tokoyomi - yes, it is possible. In larger applications, a logging library is used to allow more logging options. E.g. [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/)